# How can a last Dense layer in a multiclass model expect shape as (1,)?

Tags: python, keras

I have a multiclass problem with 15 classes. The model is as follows:

```py
def create_model(latent_dimension=1000, num_classes=15):
    input_x = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')

    conv_1 = Conv1D(16, kernel_size=(64), activation='relu')(input_x)
    maxpool_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=(4))(conv_1)
    bn_1 = BatchNormalization()(maxpool_1)

    conv_2 = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=(32), activation='relu')(bn_1)
    maxpool_2 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=(4))(conv_2)
    bn_2 = BatchNormalization()(maxpool_2)

    conv_3 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(16), activation='relu')(bn_2)
    bn_3 = BatchNormalization()(conv_3)
    conv_4 = Conv1D(128, kernel_size=(4), activation='relu')(bn_3)

    flatten = Flatten()(conv_4)
    dense1 = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(flatten)
    out = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(dense1)
    model = Model(input_x, out)

    inputA = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')
    inputB = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')
    inputC = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')
    inputD = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')
    inputE = Input(shape=(latent_dimension, 1), dtype='float32')

    cnn_out1 = model(inputA)
    cnn_out2 = model(inputB)
    cnn_out3 = model(inputC)
    cnn_out4 = model(inputD)
    cnn_out5 = model(inputE)

    combined = concatenate([cnn_out1, cnn_out2, cnn_out3, cnn_out4, cnn_out5], axis=-1)

    fully_connected = Dense(128, activation="relu")(combined)
    outputs_fc = Dense(15, activation="softmax")(fully_connected)

    model_encoded = Model(inputs=[inputA, inputB, inputC, inputD, inputE], outputs=outputs_fc)

    model_encoded.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(model_encoded.summary())

    return model_encoded
```

And in the generator for this model, I yield the data as:

```py
def data_gen():
    # some operations
    yield chx, to_categorical(chy, 15)
```

The shape of them are:

```py
print(len(chx))  # 5
print(chx[0].shape)  # (32, 1000, 1)
print(len(chy))  # 32
print(to_categorical(chy, 15).shape)  # (32, 15)
```

32 is my batch size and 5 is for the 5 inputs layers. (1000, 1) is simply a signal data.

When I try to train this model, it gives the error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (15,)`

I  can't see where the problem is. Why I can't train this model? I can provide more info if you need.